# SwiftUI transition does not work when using Group without any stacks inside

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

does anyone know why exactly views inside `Group` don't animate?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showRed = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Group {
                if showRed {
                    redView
                } else {
                    blueView
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Toggle color") {
                        showRed.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    var redView: some View {
        Text("")
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .background(.red)
            .transition(.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)))
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    var blueView: some View {
        Text("")
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .background(.blue)
            .transition(.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)))
    }
}
```

No one seems to really know why this is and the best answer I've found is "There's no container to hold the transition" which doesn't really make sense given that `Group`'s initializer is marked `@ViewBuilder` so it should return a real container view that can take modifiers like `.toolbar` in the sample above.

The transitions work if you either swap out `Group` with some `Stack` or if you wrap the conditionals inside the `Group{}` in another container like `ZStack`:

```swift
Group {
    ZStack {
        if showRed {
            redView
        } else {
            blueView
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually `Group` doesn't really create any real container, even if it has a `ViewBuilder` init, as said in documentation:

> Use a group to collect multiple views into a single instance, without affecting the layout of those views

You can simply use a `ZStack` for this

```swift
ZStack {
    if showRed {
        redView
    } else {
        blueView
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but that line is saying that adding 2 views into a `Group` won't affect their layout, unlike others like `Stack` where the moment you add them they'll move to fit the container's layout. The documentation makes it sound very much like `Group` should act like any other container view except that it doesn't move its child views around like `Stack`, but obviously `Group` isn't an actually a real container view and I'm trying to figure out why

Comment: Group is just a way to, for example, add same modifiers to multiple views or when you need more than  10 direct children (due to view builder limitation) in a parent view. When you use a group, imagine that it basically doesn’t exist